# Two questions about Fock spaces

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, mp.mathematical-physics, quantum-mechanics, quantum-field-theory

Let $\mathscr{H}$ be a complex Hilbert space and denote $\mathscr{H}_{n}$ the tensor product $\overbrace{\mathscr{H}\otimes\cdots\otimes\mathscr{H}}^{\text{n}}$. Denote by $\Pi_{\pm}$ the projection operators onto symmetric and anti-symmetric projections on $\mathscr{H}_{n}$:
$$\Pi_{+}(\psi_{1}\otimes \cdots \otimes \psi_{n}) = \frac{1}{n!}\sum_{\pi}\psi_{\pi(1)}\otimes\cdots\otimes \psi_{\pi(n)} \quad \mbox{and} \quad \Pi_{-}(\psi_{1}\otimes\cdots\otimes \psi_{n}) = \frac{1}{n!}\sum_{\pi}\operatorname{sign}(\pi)\psi_{\pi(1)}\otimes\cdots\psi_{\pi(n)}$$
where $\sum_{\pi}$ is a sum over all permutations $\pi$ of $\{1,...,n\}$. These operator can be extended to all $\mathscr{H}_{n}$ and I'll denote their images $\Pi_{\pm}(\mathscr{H}_{n})$ by $\mathscr{H}_{n}^{\pm}$.

Now, if $f \in \mathscr{H}$, let's take the usual creation and annihilation operators $b^{\dagger}(f)$ and $b(f)$, defined by means of the following conditions:
$$b^{\dagger}(f)(\psi_{1}\otimes \cdots \otimes \psi_{n}) = \sqrt{n+1}(f \otimes \psi_{1}\otimes \cdots \otimes \psi_{n})$$
$$b(f)(\psi_{1}\otimes \cdots \otimes \psi_{n}) =\sqrt{n}\langle f,\psi_{1}\rangle (\psi_{2}\otimes \cdots \otimes \psi_{n})$$
Again, these extend to bounded linear operators on $\mathscr{H}_{n}$. Depending on what subspace $\Pi_{\pm}(\mathscr{H}_{n})$ one wants to consider, one can define $a^{\dagger}(f) = \Pi_{\pm}b^{\dagger}(f)$ and $a(f) = \Pi_{\pm}b(f)$. One can prove:
$$a^{\dagger}(f)\Pi_{n}^{\pm}(\psi_{1}\otimes \cdots \otimes \psi_{n}) = \sqrt{n+1}\Pi_{n+1}^{\pm}(f\otimes \psi_{1}\otimes \cdots \otimes \psi_{n}). \tag{1}\label{1}$$

We can extend our analysis to symmetric and anti-symmetric Fock spaces $\mathcal{F}^{\pm}(\mathscr{H}) = \bigoplus_{n=0}^{\infty}(\mathscr{H}_{n}^{\pm})$. In this case, we extend both $a^{\dagger}(f)$ and $a(f)$ to a dense subspace of $\mathcal{F}^{\pm}(\mathscr{H})$, which is the space of finitely many particles $\mathcal{D}_{0} := \{\psi \in \mathcal{F}^{\pm}(\mathscr{H}): \mbox{there exists $N \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $\psi_{n} = 0$ for every $n \ge N$}\}$, by letting each of these operators to act componentwise. By using (\ref{1}), we see that this dense set can be built from sucessive creation of particles, i.e:
$$\Pi^{\pm}(f_{1}\otimes \cdots \otimes f_{n}) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{n!}}a^{\dagger}(f_{1})\cdots a^{\dagger}(f_{1})\Omega_{0} \tag{2}\label{2}$$
where $\Omega_{0} = (1,0,0,...) \in \mathcal{F}^{\pm}(\mathscr{H})$ is the vacuum state.

**Question 1:** It is usually used, specially in the physics literature, that *every* linear operator $A$ on $\mathcal{F}^{\pm}(\mathscr{H})$ can be written in terms of creation and annihilation operators. However, I have never seen any proof of this result, and it does not seem trivial to me. Is this a provable fact?

**Question 2:** How can we change the above scenario to include time evolution? More especifically, let $H$ be a Hamiltonian on $\mathscr{H}$. At least if the particles of the system are noninteracting, the time evolution operator on $\mathscr{H}_{n}$ is $e^{-itH_{n}} = e^{-itH}\otimes \cdots \otimes e^{-itH}$, where there are $n$ such tensor products. In Heisenberg's picture, one defined time-dependent operators, i.e:
$$a^{\dagger}(f,t) := e^{itH_{n}}a^{\dagger}(f)e^{-itH_{n}} \tag{3}\label{3}$$
On the other hand, we can evolve elements:
$$e^{-itH_{n}}(\Pi^{\pm}(f_{1}\otimes \cdots \otimes f_{n})) \tag{4}\label{4}$$
Does it follow from (\ref{1}) and (\ref{2}) that every such time-evolved element can be built from sucessive applications of $a^{\dagger}(f,t)$?

**Add:** Question 2 is better rephrased as follows. If time is considered, does (\ref{2}) still holds when the creation operators $a^{\dagger}(f_{i})$ on the right hand side of this equation is replaced by the time-dependent (\ref{3}) and the left hand side of (\ref{2}) is replaced by (\ref{4})?

Comment: In Question 1, you did not make very precise what you mean by "can be written in terms of creation and annihilation operators". It is not true that the algebra generated by creation and annihilation operators is all operators. However, it is dense in the strong operator topology. Equivalently, the von Neumann algebra generated by the creation and annihilation operators is all operators. For the full Fock space, this is proven in  https://mathoverflow.net/q/105922, but I think the same proof works for the symmetric and anti-symmetric Fock spaces.

Comment: For question 2, what is the definition of "a time-evolved element"?

Comment: @MikaeldelaSalle thanks for the link and the comments. To answer your question, if $\psi \in \mathcal{F}^{\pm}(\mathscr{H})$ is an arbitrary element, the time-evolved element is $e^{-itH}\psi$. I edited the post to clarify this second question!